# Aggregate results along with respective record names

Tags: apex, soql, aggregate, aggregateresult

How to get the MAX(Amount), Min(Amount) from a list of opportunity records with respective Opportunity Names in a single SOQL query.

```
for(AggregateResult agResult : [Select Name, MIN(Amount) 'MinAmount', MAX(Amount) 'MaxAmount' 
                                 from Opportunity group by Name]){

     Decimal opMinAmount = (Decimal)agResult.get('MinAmount');
     Decimal opMaxAmount = (Decimal)agResult.get('MaxAmount');   
     String maxAmountOpName = agResult.get(Name);
     //How to get the Minimum Amount Opportunity Name.
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a single query (though I could be mistaken).

Comment: @Phil- Yes, it cannot be achieved in a single SOQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you would want to use would like:

```
select
  name, amount
from
  opportunity
where
  id = (
    select id from opportunity
    order by amount asc
    limit 1
  )
  or id = (
    select id from opportunity
    order by amount desc
    limit 1
  )
order by
  amount asc
```

However... this isn't SOQL. It's SQL. Unfortunately, SOQL doesn't support this syntax.

You'll need two queries to get the min and max values.

Comment: Rocking as usual